# Check boxes not working

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Help, there is something wrong with my checkboxes.
I'm trying to make a form with checkboxes. However, when I tick only one checkbox, all the checkboxes will also be ticked and the data will be inserted into the database.

This is my code below,

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        function showComment() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "registerarray.php",
                data: "action=showcomment",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#comment").html(data);
                }
            });
        }
        showComment();

        $("#send").click(function () {

            var starttime = $("#starttime").val();
            var endtime = $("#endtime").val();
            var monday = $("#monday").val();
            var tuesday = $("#tuesday").val();
            var wednesday = $("#wednesday").val();
            var thursday = $("#thursday").val();
            var saturday = $("#saturday").val();
            var friday = $("#friday").val();
            var sunday = $("#sunday").val();

            var dataString = "starttime1=" + starttime + "&endtime1=" + endtime + "&monday1=" + monday + "&tuesday1=" + tuesday + "&wednesday1=" + wednesday + "&thursday1=" + thursday + "&friday1=" + friday + "&saturday1=" + saturday + "&sunday1=" + sunday + "&action=addcomment";

            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "registerarray.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function (data) {
                    showComment();
                    $("#formTable")[0].reset();

                }

            });

        });
    });

<div id="formbox"> 
                <form id="formTable">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <lable>Start time</lable>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="startTime" id="starttime">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <lable>End time</lable>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="endTime" id="endtime">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <lable>Monday</lable>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="Monday" value="1" id="monday">
                        <lable>Tuesday</lable>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="Tuesday" value="1" id="tuesday">
                        <lable>Wednesday</lable>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="Wednesday" value="1" id="wednesday">
                        <lable>Thursday</lable>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="Thursday" value="1" id="thursday">
                        <lable>Friday</lable>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="Friday" value="1" id="friday">
                        <lable>Saturday</lable>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="Saturday" value="1" id="saturday">
                        <lable>Sunday</lable>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="Sunday" value="1" id="sunday">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Add" id="send">
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
```

Please help thanks

Comment: you need to find if your checkbox is checked prior to sending the values in ajax

Comment: give them separate values  they are all set to 1

Comment: @fighter7788 if you got your answer then approved answer or tell us if any thing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change some things. First you need to read what is checked:

```
  var monday = $('#monday').is(':checked') //true if is checked
```

You need to change label tag, because you are writting `lable` and its incorrect

```
   <label for="monday">Monday</label>
```

Comment: I gotten zero despite checking the check box

Comment: Please, read the code. Note that I missing the `#` character to selector by id. Now is in the code `$('#monday')` instead of `$('monday')` that I've been writting last. It must works

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.is(":checked")` method instead of `val()` method like given below.

```
var monday = $("#monday").is(":checked");
```

`.val()` always returns value of `checkbox` regardless of it is `checked` or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use other answers also and they all are correct , But there is another option also available , As per your code I can see that you want all elements from your form and want to call ajax, For that you can also use serialize() option for the same.

```
var parameters = $("#formTable").serialize();
console.log(parameters);
```

Check this url [serialize elements](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I Solve it using this,

```
if(document.getElementById('monday').checked) {
                var monday = $("#monday").val();
            }
```

Thanks to everyone that helped :)